# Binding Indexer

Tags: xaml, binding, win-universal-app

I have a collection of items in my app, and I want to set the `Content` of a `ContentPresenter` to one of these items. The item will be randomly defined by an `int` index. I can bind an item like this:

```
<ContentPresenter Content={Binding Items[0]}/>
```

but not like this:

```
<ContentPresenter Content={Binding Items[{Binding Index}]}/>
```

I've seen a number of answers suggesting using `MultiBinding` in WPF, but this isn't available in UWP. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a view model property, returning `Items[Index]`:

```
public string RandomItem => Items[Index];
```

For the `PropertyChanged` notifications to work, you will need to raise the event whenever `Index` or `Items` changes, e.g.:

```
public int Index
{
    get { return _index; }
    set
    {
        _index = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => RandomItem);
    }
}
```

If you prefer to have the logic in the view and go the multi-binding way, you can use the [Cimbalino toolkit](https://github.com/Cimbalino/Cimbalino-Toolkit). For that to work, first add 2 NuGet packages:

- [Cimbalino.Toolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cimbalino.Toolkit/)
- [Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed/)

Now you can create a converter:

```
public class CollectionIndexConverter : MultiValueConverterBase
{
    public override object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var collection = (IList) values[0];
        var index = (int?) values[1];
        return index.HasValue ? collection[index.Value] : null;
    }

    public override object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And use it from XAML:

```
<ContentPresenter>
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:MultiBindingBehavior PropertyName="Content" Converter="{StaticResource CollectionIndexConverter}">
            <behaviors:MultiBindingItem Value="{Binding Items}" />
            <behaviors:MultiBindingItem Value="{Binding Index}" />
        </behaviors:MultiBindingBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ContentPresenter>
```